# Slamdata error when mounting: An unknown error ocurred: 500 ""

Tags: mongodb, slamdata

I have once before mounted this same database, so I am confident that I have the correct credentials. 
During the last session that I had it mounted I was experimenting with my queries, visuals etc. and the session all of a sudden crashed. 
Then when I reloaded slamdata, the mount for my database was gone.
Obviously I then tried to remount the same database with the same credentials in order to continue my work. However when I did this I got an error:

There was a problem saving the mount: An unknown error ocurred: 500 ""

And then there is a never ending spin wheel that sits on the mount button. I can leave this pop up and go to the original screen, but nothing occurs. And then if  I try to remount again the same error occurs.

I have verified that I can still access my db and collections using robomongo. So if anyone knows what this error message  refers to please let me know! I have yet to find its meaning online.

Note: I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling/ restarted my computer.

Comment: There is insufficient information provided to reproduce the problem.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then revise your question. Also, have you searched the web?  What did you find and why is your problem different?

Comment: This was a bug on slamdata's side. Hence why it was difficult to reproduce/illustrate how the problem came to be. I contacted technical services and am posting the fix below.

Comment: Glad you found a fix.

Answer (score 0):

In SlamData 4.2.1 this bug has been identified and fixed an issue with the MongoDB connecter that would corrupt the metastore if you use the `_id` field in a query. The fix is available in the SlamData 4.2.2 release soon

Below is the fix:

1. Delete the current metastore. Below is the location of this file for each supported operating system:

   **Mac OS:**

   > $HOME/Library/Application Support/quasar/quasar-metastore.db.mv.db

   **Microsoft Windows:**

   > %HOMEDIR%\AppData\Local\quasar\quasar-metastore.db.mv.db

   **Linux (various vendors):**

   > $HOME/.config/quasar/quasar-metastore.db.mv.db
2. Open a terminal and switch to the location that you stored SlamData into. You should find a `quasar-web.jar` file in the following location based on your installed operating system based on default installation paths:

   **Mac OS:**

   > /Applications/SlamData 4.2.1.app/Contents/java/app/quasar-web.jar

   **Microsoft Windows:**

   > C:\Program Files (x86)\slamdata 4.2.1\quasar-web.jar

   **Linux (various vendors):**

   > $HOME/SlamData 4.2.1/quasar-web.jar
3. Run the following command in a terminal:

   `java -jar quasar-web.jar initUpdateMetaStore`

   This will rebuild your metastore. Once complete it will return you to your operating system prompt.
4. Rerun the SlamData application as you normally would
5. Remount your database
6. At this point in time you can access your saved workspaces.

NOTE: You will not want to open the workspace you were using that caused this issue as it will cause the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed solution. I got an error when attempting to delete the `quasar-metastore.db.mv.db` file. "This action cannot be completed because the file is open in Slam Data Advanced.exe". Any idea how to get rid of this?
EDIT: Fixed it by stopping the exe process from Task Manager.

Comment: Another error: When attempting to remount database, it says *There was a problem saving the mount: AJAX request failed: GET /metadata/fs/*.